# How to import a svg and get the text correct without hand-editing pdf_tex file?

Tags: latex

I'd like to import multiple visio diagrams into my latex document.. I've managed to achieve the actual svg import, but the text is not appearing how the original document looks..

Here is an original [image]

But when I import it as a SVG I get the text "unwrapped"
[image]

I'm using the SVG package

This might be related https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/inkscape-loses-text-coordinates-when-exporting-for-latex#54980

Comment: You could disable automatic line breaks in Visio and add them manually, which would be honored by other programs, but I don't know if that's enough to solve the problem. Personally I would export the graphics as png.

Comment: Yes I normally do - but this document is starting to get huge on disk and pdf'd :)

Comment: Another possibility would be to create the graphics within latex (here are some good examples with tikz https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/). It would be some upfront investment to get it running, but may be worth it, depending on your use-case(s).

Comment: I, too, would do this in tikz.

Comment: Unfortunately its coming from iServer which is an enterprise architecture system doing a lot more than simple diagrams - these are data drive stuff with complex shape objects - there is no way I could reproduce it in Tikz

Comment: I'm thinking some scripting might help it work - it would mean pre-processing from Inkscape and not using \includesvg but I think the lack of pain might be worth it - I am puzzled as to why it shows fine in Inkscape, but when it exports it sends the text as plain text - I might look at see if there is a switch to stop that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - it looks like the solution might be a bit easier than I thought! - I have to test it a bit more though..

Normally /includesvg and all the instructions out there tell you to use the following

```
inkscape -D my.svg -o my.pdf --export-latex
```

but if you do

```
inkscape -T -D my.svg -o my.pdf --export-latex
```

Now all text has been converted to paths (yes it no longer following your font style in the body) and gets rolled up into a single pdf

Comment: it doesn't work quite right.. often it only generates a pdf (valid and embeddable) and not pdf_tex - but a bunch of complaints about not understanding things "WARNING: unknown type: v:documentProperties
WARNING: unknown type: v:custProps
WARNING: unknown type: v:userDefs
WARNING: unknown type: v:pageProperties
WARNING: unknown type: v:layer
WARNING: unknown type: v:layer
WARNING: unknown type: v:layer
WARNING: unknown type: v:layer
WARNING: unknown type: v:layer
WARNING: unknown type: v:layer...
"